# Azure Devops pipeline finish with warning badge when a job failed

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a pipeline (Azure Devops yaml) with some jobs.
They run in parallel.
But when one fails, the build ends with a warning and not an error badge.
Why?
I expected the pipeline to end in error.

[image]

**Edit:**
pipelines.yml

```yaml
pool:
  name: Default


jobs:
- job: FirstJob
  steps:
  - script: echo First!

- template: template.yml
  parameters:
     name: Second

- template: template.yml
  parameters:
     name: Third

- template: template.yml
  parameters:
     name: Fourth

- template: template.yml
  parameters:
     name: Fifth

- template: template.yml
  parameters:
     name: Sixth

- template: template.yml
  parameters:
     name: Seventh
```

template.yml:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: name
    type: string
    default: -- 

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.name }}
  dependsOn: FirstJob
  continueOnError: true
  variables:
      BuildTag: ${{ parameters.name }}

  steps:
    - task : AddTag@0
      inputs:
        tags: '$(BuildTag)'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: 'foo'
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['BuildTag'], 'Sixth'))
```

I see my mistake with **continueOnError: true**.

Comment: I have created a sample, but could not reproduce this issue, would you mind share a simple sample, like yaml file to me, so that I could reproduce this issue? Are there any settings in your project?

Comment: I will try to something. All jobs (except first one) are coming from a template. is it possible that it is a race condition? different jobs on same agent? I have slightly fewer agents than jobs. this is from onprem agents.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT With the sample, I could see my mistake.

On the other hand, even if the build finish with a 'warning badge' in a PR policies 'warning' = 'success'. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I just got free from other threads. I could reproduce this issue with your sample, you could check my answer for some more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Azure Devops pipeline finish with warning badge when a job failed

Thanks for your comments and sample, which make me found out the reason for this issue:

The property **`continueOnError`**. **This behavior is by designed** and is not a bug. There is no way to fix it at present.

If we set the `continueOnError: true`,  which will make the future jobs should run even if this job fails. In order to achieve it, Azure Devops will use a *"deceptive way"* to treat error as warning, so that the error will not prevent the building. That the reason why the job failed, but the pipeline show it as warning.

We could even just reproduce this issue with Control Options `Continue on error` in non-YAML task:

[image]

[image]

Besides, it does not affect the completion of the PR.

**To resolve this issue**, you could comment it in the YAML. If it is necessary for you, you could set the `condition: always()` for the future jobs:

```
jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.name }}
  dependsOn: FirstJob
  variables:
      BuildTag: ${{ parameters.name }}

  steps:
   ...

- job: Second
  condition: always()

- job: Third
  condition: always()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u need to uncheck "advanced" => "FAIL ON STDERR" (If this option is selected, the build will fail when the remote commands or script write to STDERR).